# Bash github project fails to run when cloned on WSL Ubuntu

Tags: bash, git, shell, github, wsl-2

I have a simple bash script written on a WSL Ubuntu system; it runs perfectly there. I then `git push` it up to github, and go to a different systems WSL Ubuntu and `git clone` the project, cd into that folder and run the script, but it is broken with the below errors.

I tried `dos2unix` on it, but this does not work, same errors and same broken state. Do you have some suggestions about what might be causing this (something is changed by storing it in github I guess), and how to fix (as before, none of the below errors are seen on the originating WSL Ubuntu system, where the script runs perfectly)?

```
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: invalid shell option name
: command not found
: command not found
-bash: .custom: line 147: syntax error near unexpected token `$'{\r''
'bash: .custom: line 147: `fnheader() {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with Windows line endings, so my solution was:

```
# Remove cloned repo
git config --global core.autocrlf input
# Clone again the repo
```

Let me know if it works for you too.

Regards.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks. I still don't really understand why this happens though... If I upload to github from WSL Ubuntu, a normal Linux fs, and then clone into a different WSL Ubuntu, I would expect nothing to have Windows line-endings?. And, if they did, I would have thought that dos2unix would fix that? 